# Two SQL query inside single JasperReport and populating Data

Tags: jasper-reports, reporting, ireport

We are using reports in our web application.
The report is generated using *JasperReports*.

The problem I am facing is:

My SQL query fetches data based on a where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE level='c'
```

I can easily show this information inside the *iReport*.

But I need to fire another query where `level='d'` and the information for the same needs to be appended to the report with that of `level='c'`.

I tried grouping both the outputs. But problem is how do I fire two different query while generating the report because I can write only one query in QueryBuilder inside the *iReport*.

Is there anyway of achieving the same.

In essence:

The report should look like:

```
Level=C
Name Age Phone number

Level=D
Name Age Phone number
```

Level D should appear only after level c is completed.

Can anyone please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve the same..Grouping the data using level_id..
Initially I was trying to group in a different manner and hence the value was not getting shown..

The same is explained pretty nicely in ireport Ultimate guide-3 document.